# Cross-Validation for Unsupervised Anomaly Detection with Isolation Forest

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation, unsupervised-learning, isolation-forest

I am wondering whether I can perform any kind of Cross-Validation or GridSearchCV for unsupervised learning. The thing is that I have the ground truth labels (but since it is unsupervised I just drop them for training and then reuse them for measuring accuracy, auc, aucpr, f1-score over the test set).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "way"? A specific method or a concept/pseudo-code?

Comment: I don't need neither a specific method nor pseudo-code, I was just wondering if this is possible and if so, how would it work; maybe some reference about it, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can use scikit-learn's [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) with an unsupervised algorithm. Since scikit-learn's Isolation Forest does not have a score function, a custom scoring function has to be implemented. It would something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.ensemble        import IsolationForest
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

def scorer(estimator, X): 
    "Custom scoring function"
    return np.mean(estimator.score_samples(X))

if_gs = GridSearchCV(IsolationForest(), scoring=scorer)
if_gs.fit(X)
```